# Using Ajax on a Facebook-aware PHP website causes API 191 error

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

Ok, so I have got an App ID and secret for a website.

When I set that up, I had to specify a URL.

This points to the main PHP page (lets call it main.php), which uses the PHP SDK to interact with facebook.

However, I want to call another PHP file (lets call it process.php), using Ajax, to process data and update the stream.

Now, I could create another facebook application for process.php, with its own id and secret, but that would be messy and you would have to grant it facebook permissions etc separately.

But if I use the application id and secret that I used in main.php, I get the following message:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application
configuration.
```

I am sure there must be a way to do this, but I can't for the life of me see what it is.

Comment: post some code of what you are trying to do.
if you are trying to redirect the user in order to authorize your app - make sure that you defined app domain in the app properties and that the redirect_uri that you are passing to facebook (in order to return to after the authorization) is under the same domain

Comment: Could you not set the url to something like `http://yoursite.com` I have done this and very similar things worked fine for me

Comment: In the process of producing a stripped down example of what I was trying to do I think I have stumbled upon the problem. Well, two actually. There was a typo in the secret in the ajax.php file. However, once that had been corrected it still wasn't working. The problem was I had stored some access tokens in variables, and was reusing them. However, the access tokens had expired. I am trying again without storing the access token.

Comment: Dale, you were right in what you said. The URL redirect was a complete red herring. The URL can be just a domain on facebook, and you can have different files sharing the same codes. I have demonstrated that at least.